# Get actual URL from address bar in Classic ASP on a 404 redirected page

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I need to catch URLs that don't exist on my website and redirect them to relevant pages that do exist.

I have set up a custom 404 page on the web server and then in the 404 I look at the URL, decide where it should be going and then forward the page as follows:

```
Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"
Response.AddHeader("Location",thisPageString)
```

Where thisPageString is the new page URL.

However, when I access the page URL with...

```
Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO")
```

...I get the current actual URL = "/404.asp"; when what I actually need is the original URL for the non-existent page shown in the address bar.

How do I access that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You should get the info you are looking for from

<strike>request.servervariables("http_referer")</strike>

**Update:**

Try

```
request.servervariables("QUERY_STRING")
```

you should get the info separated by ";"

Example: **"404;http://unknown.asp"**

Comment: Or even simpler: Request.QueryString

Comment: I use `Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING")` in my custom 404-pages as a simple 'URL rewrite'. Works great.